# Have 2 different TableViews in one UIView

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I have 2 tableviews in my view right now.
One is grouped: where I can press and push to another view(like a menu)
the other one is plain: where I want to show the searchresults

I know I can use the displaycontroller but I don't know how to show the results on the table

Can someone tell me more about this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are showing only one tableview at a time right?

A tableview's style cannot be changed once created.  If you want to avoid creating two tableviews in IB, you can instead create one tableview at runtime.  When creating the tableview, you can tell it what style you want using its `initWithFrame:style:` method.

Comment: But one tableview is like "options" and the other one is the searchbar with a tableview how do I show the results on the tableview of the searchbar

Comment: The UISearchBar can also be created at runtime and set as the tableHeaderView of the tableview (if the view is in "search mode").